# How to fix PHP exec not running, but command works on linux terminal?

Tags: php

I have the following script to delete a folder.

```
_log('to_delete: '.$to_delete_uploadFolder); 
// Returns: to_delete: temp/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum/

exec('rm -rf '.escapeshellarg('var/www/html/web/'.$to_delete_uploadFolder).'2>&1', $output);

print_r($output);
// Returns: Array ( )
```

If I am in the project folder (web/ in this case), and I do `ls temp/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum/` to verify the path, it exists.

I already look the php.ini file and it does not contain exec under disable_functions. It has pcntl_exec there, but that is for something else.

Also, the folder permissions are as described below:

```
drwxrwxrwx 12 ubuntu   ubuntu    4096 Mar  4 18:25  temp
drwxrwxrwx   2 ubuntu   ubuntu    4096 Feb 10 19:55 2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum
```

This is Ubuntu 20.04 and PHP 7.3

Comment: Try removing the `.'2>&1'` from the exec, i.e. `exec($cmd, $output);` and see what the $output is.  That is probably hiding your error from you.  Since your permisions are wide open, I suspect the process running php cannot find `rm` so you may need to provide the full path to it.

Comment: @Alan after removing the ```.'2>&1'``` the output is the same. Tried also with ```$cmd = "rm -rf web/temp/2016_Corpus_Christi_Cotton_and_Sorghum/ 2>&1";``` and the result is the same

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg before you accidentally your entire folder structure.

Comment: Does the folder where the code is matter or it will always execute from the projects folder (web/)?

Comment: Oh yes use escapeshellarg as Sammitch recommended.  I also recommend absolute path for rm and for the directory you want to delete just to be sure.  I think I ran into a similar issue in the past where I had to do that.